# Passing Querystring style parameters into Javascript file

Tags: javascript

Not sure if this is possible or even if I should do it, but I think it's quite interesting.

I have a javascript file which I'm referencing in a flat HTML page.  I'd like to pass in a parameter or two via the path to the script.  Like this;

```
<script src="/scripts/myJavascriptFile.js?config1=true" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Not really sure if it can work but it would make my solution a little easier for others to take my script and implement (arguable).

Cheers,
Mike

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that passing in variables via the `src` attribute is possible out of the box without some extra coding on your part (there is an article [here](http://blog.theaccidentalgeek.com/post/2008/08/21/Passing-parameters-to-JavaScript-files.aspx) if you are interested!). You could do the following though, which should provide the same functionality as you are looking for:

Define your "config" variables in a single script block on your HTML page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var config1 = true;
</script>
```

Reference your external JS file in a second script block:

```
<script src="/scripts/myJavascriptFile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Add this code to your external JS file to reference the "local" variable in your HTML:

```
var conf1 = window.config1;

if (conf1) {
  // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation on Matt's answer. I have a similar case where I need a jQuery file to use a value that is generated in the HTML (by Razor in this case). I write the value to a meta tag, generated as it is from the controller:

```
<meta name="sessionId" content="@ViewBag.SessionId">
```

and then read it in the jQuery file:

```
var sessionId = $("meta[name=sessionId]").attr("content");
```

It's not quite the same as passing it in by querystring, but useful if that information is considered "meta-information" of the HTML page.