# What do I get an error with highcharts, only in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, highcharts, trim

The charts are working ok in most browsers, including firefox and Opera.  However in IE I am getting:

```
Object doesn't support this property or method
report_graph.js
Code: 0
URI: http://10.11.4.92:5000/assets/report_graph.js?body=1
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot just of the window? Awful hard to read.

Comment: You have to post the code inside report_graph.js, try to debug your code, probably you'll see where it happens.

Comment: Hi Michael, yes it's via virtual box which is why it was weird.  I put the actual text above.

Comment: Hi Ricardo, yeah this would be a cinch if I could get it to happen on my (Mac) machine for local development.  As I couldn't and this is _only_ an IE8 problem I am using virtual box to see it, but I think this makes debugging it hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *It wa all due to a `.trim() at the end of some of the code !*

e.g. I had `$('some selectors).text().trim()`

Changing it to `$('some selectors).text().trim()` fixed it.

As it actually has worked ok in some browsers this seems to suggest an actual issue with the javascript engine in IE.  Either it doesn't support the method that other browsers do... or it does not handle the error as gracefully, causing a runtime exception for a error that other browser ignore.

Comment: It seems there is a typo, you said twice the same thing : $('some selectors).text().trim()

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you're calling the javascript file along with a query-string attached. Check out: [Passing Querystring style parameters into Javascript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021737/passing-querystring-style-parameters-into-javascript-file) and [Passing parameters to JavaScript files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190801/passing-parameters-to-javascript-files) for possible solutions.