# How to pass search string to javascript from javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've been using the following dynamic scripting technique for executing a site-specific subroutine in an otherwise generic script, viz

```
siteExtras : function (cid, extras) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = 'https://' + cid + '.mysite.com/' + cid + "_extras.js?" + extras;
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  var h = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  h.parentNode.insertBefore(script, h);
},
```

So given the following invocation

```
this.siteExtras('cycles','concept=tandem');
```

script.src thus becomes

```
https://cycles.mysite.com/cycles_extras.js?concept=tandem
```

where cycles is a client-specific subdomain I've created on mysite.com.

The issue I'm having is that I've been assuming that cycles_extras.js would be capable of reading it's own search string, using

```
//cycles_extras.js
function getParameterByName(name) {
    var args = location.search.substr(1).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        var parts = args[i].split('=');
        if (name === parts[0]) {
            return unescape(parts[1]);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
var concept = getParameterByName('concept');
...
```

however, when cycles_extras.js is executed, it takes its location.search from the browser, not from the https://cycles.mysite.com/cycles_extras.js?concept=tandem URL.

Am I attempting the impossible here? Or is something missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021737/passing-querystring-style-parameters-into-javascript-file

Comment: you can use global namespace for help. Bind the values to a variable and attach it to window or document objects. Example, document.concept = "tandem" or window.concept = "tandem"

Comment: @SelvamPalanimalai - please make your comment an answer. Then I can give it a big green tick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use global namespace for help. Bind the values to a variable and attach it to window or document objects. Example,

```
document.concept = "tandem" 

window.concept = "tandem".
```